# MobaXterm: How to open an ssh-browser without using a saved session

Tags: mobaxterm

I usually use MobaXterm local terminal and connect to dozens of different hosts via ssh.

I do not use saved sessions.
Is it possible to open the ssh-browser for file transfer from the local terminal?

Start MobaXterm => Start local terminal:

```
me@MyDesktop:~> ssh remotehost
```

< I want to see the ssh browser here >